# How to print Java code on A3 page avoiding line-wrapping

Tags: printing, word-wrap

I have to print Java code that some times reaches 300 columns (characters per line) in A3 paper and whatever editor I use (e.g. textmate) wraps the lines in order to fit in A4 paper.

Any suggestions?

cheers,
Asterios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it to print using enscript. Here is the command I used to print Java code into PDF (and the used the pdf to print).

```
enscript -r -Ejava -M A3 -C -f "Courier8" input.java -o - |  ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

where:

- -r  prints in landscape mode
- -C prints the line numbers
- -f changes the font and size
- -M sets the output media to A3 (default is A4)
- -Ejava adds syntax highlighting (you can also use --color if you need
  colors in syntax highlighting but
  they are not nicely printed in
  greyscale)

Answer (score 1):

Your editor undoubtably has either a Page Setup dialog or a Preferences dialogue as part of the Print Dialogue which will allow you to set the Paper Size to use for printing.

Even Notepad supports this

Comment: Yes, finally textmate does have a dialog. Hoever, I have used enscript as it can be used in a script to print a lot of code if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely that every editor tries to format for A4. Which other editors have you tried? Does textmate not have a page size option? (Hmm... [seems not](http://wiki.macromates.com/Suggestions/Preferences))

Try a different editor that does let you set page size. Word, even.